# python3.7 bulk title extraction from URL's using asyncio and aiohttp

Tags: python, asynchronous, aiohttp

I want to get the titles of all the websites in a list.
This is what I am using right now

https://gist.github.com/PandaWhoCodes/e6a4621d3b09889a98d12e67bb8c4cf9

This still takes a good 5 minutes to run on 600 URL's.
Is there a way I can make this process even faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to debug and/or profile network part. Looks like you have some limitation for connections/bandwidth — maybe your ISP or services throttling your requests.

Your code is totally fine, it finishes in seconds. Profiling shows that top 3 "own time" (most consuming by itself, without call chain) nodes is

- epoll select
- zlib decompress
- `bytes.decode`

This is ~50% of total runtime.

Comment: 600 links in a few seconds ?

Comment: I'll try testing it on an ec2 instance